# Docker recognizes GPU but not Nvidia Drivers

Tags: docker, driver, nvidia, numba, nvidia-docker

I need to cuda develop a python program through docker but it seems that docker does not recognize nvidia drivers. The dockerfile builds and runs normally but when i run the python program `numba.cuda.is_available()` returns false even though `numba.cuda.gpus` returns my gpu. I have installed nvidia-docker2 and nvidia images run with nvidia-smi have the same output with nvidia-smi locally

```
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:29:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   38C    P8     9W / 125W |    358MiB /  6144MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM pure/python:3.6-cuda10.2-base



# Set the working directory to /attack/toy-rnn/dash
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app



#RUN nvcc --version

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
ENV PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin:$PATH"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-ml.list
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends graphviz less \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& pip install --no-cache-dir pyparsing pydot
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsof

RUN pip install -e iirs
RUN pip install -e simple-websocket-server-master

RUN pip install conda
#COPY /NVIDIA-Linux/libnvidia-nvvm.so.515.65.01 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/cuda/cudadrv
#RUN conda install cudatoolkit
RUN pip install numba

ENV PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin:$PATH"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all
RUN numba -s
ENV CYBER_PORT "5000"
ENV CYBER_API_CALL "/ag-engine-server/rest/json/v2/attack-graph/remediations/block-nodes"
ENV CYBER_GET_ACTIONS "/remediations"
ENV TMP_GRAPH_FILE "tmp/attack_graph_received.json"
ENV IIRS_PORT "17891"
ENV IDS_IP "0.0.0.0"
ENV IDS_PORT "36010"
ENV IDS_API_CALL "/test"

ENV IGNORE_ALERT_TIMESTAMPS "True"
ENV IGNORE_TMS_ALERTS "True"

ENV ANTI_CONGESTION "True"
# In seconds, float.
ENV ALERT_CONGESTION_THRESHOLD "0.5"

# This will ignore "flow" alerts with the field "alerted" set to false.
ENV IGNORE_ALERTED_FALSE "True"
ENV COMPROMISED_THRESHOLD "0.5"
ENV TMS_THRESHOLD "0.4"
# Whether to enable the POMCP model.
ENV ENABLE_GT_MODEL "True"
# Do we consider all not blocked exploits to be available?
# "Strict" or "Typical"
ENV GENERATOR_POLICY "Strict"
ENV GENERATOR_OVERRIDE_BUS_MSG "False"
# In milliseconds
ENV UI_ACTION_PENDING_TIMEOUT "60000"

# - POMCP Settings ------------------------------------------------------------
# Originally set to 1500
ENV NO_PARTICLES "2"
ENV EMPTY_OBSERVATION_UPDATES "True"
ENV FORCE_GENERAL_RULES_ONLY "False"
# 0.14 sec * number of loops per particle (timeout) = ~2 min
# Originally set to 80
ENV POSTERIOR_SAMPLE_TIMEOUT "80"
# MAX_EMPTY_ACTION_ROUNDS will be considered only if ENABLE_RESTARTS is True
ENV ENABLE_RESTARTS "True"
ENV MAX_EMPTY_ACTION_ROUNDS "3"



# - LOCAL DEBUG ---------------------------------------------------------------
ENV CYBER_IP "172.17.0.1"
ENV BUS_PREFIX "5002."
ENV BUS_USER ""
ENV BUS_PASSWORD ""
ENV BUS_IP "172.17.0.1"
ENV BUS_PORT "61613"

WORKDIR /app/iirs
EXPOSE 17891
CMD ["python", "/app/iirs/api.py"]
```

I run dockerfile with this command -> `sudo docker run -d -e NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=compute,utility -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all --name $CONTAINER_NAME --network host $CONTAINER_NAME`

Any help would be greatly appreciated